# How do I model the device, in order to test my serial communication?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to talk to a device over a USB-RS232 convertor, using [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

My first test was to forgo the communication and just "invent" datapoints, in order to test the intgration of the communication class wiht the rest of the program.

```
def run(self):
    import random
    while True:
        self.callback(random.ranint(MIN, MAX))
```

Worked fine. Now I want to test "short-circuit" communication. That is, short pins 2 and 3 (there is no flow control) and receive what I am transmitting.

This works fine in `minicom`, but not with my code:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        self.ser.write('a')
        print self.ser.read(size=1)
```

The read and write timeouts are set to 0.

> timeout = None: wait forever
>   timeout = 0: non-blocking mode (return immediately on read)
>   timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed)

[image]

My program hangs after calling `write()`. What did I miss?

Comment: *"short-circuit" communication" -- Proper term is "loop-back".  I don't know Python, but in other languages/environments, unless there's a default device (e.g. `stdout`) you have to `open()` the device and configure the port.  (Although loop-back mode can work with almost any config.)

Comment: @sawdust, thanks for the term. The device is opened in the constructor: `The port is immediately opened on object creation`. I suspect my problem is within the timeouts of writing and reading. Or maybe I should be using threads.

Comment: Here's a quick test from py2.6.6 interpreter on Debian Wheezy using an FTDI USB/RS232 cable with RX and TX shorted: http://pastebin.com/CMPbVN6s .

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from the library's tests:

```
def test2_Loopback(self):
"""timeout: each sent character should return (binary test).
this is also a test for the binary capability of a port."""
    for block in segments(bytes_0to255):
        length = len(block)
        self.s.write(block)
        # there might be a small delay until the character is ready (especially on win32)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        self.failUnlessEqual(self.s.inWaiting(), length, "expected exactly %d character for inWainting()" % length)
        self.failUnlessEqual(self.s.read(length), block)#, "expected a %r which was written before" % block)
    self.failUnlessEqual(self.s.read(1), data(''), "expected empty buffer after all sent chars are read")
```

from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/code/461/tree/trunk/pyserial/test/test.py). It appears that what I was missing was the comment in the middle.

Edit: **sawdust**'s comment below solves this problem in a much neater way. Use that instead.

---

And now for the real solution.

It turns out that my problem was very silly. I was doing:

1. Open the port with no timeout or reads and writes
2. Runt an infinite loop of `write()`, then `read()`
3. Short out RX and TX with a knife or a paperclip
4. Wait and scratch my head why everything is frozen

What was happening: The write was successful, but the data was lost (as RX and TX were not yet joined). Then the read(), froze, waiting for something to hear.

I solved it by *first* shorting the pins, *then* running the test.

Comment: If you're setup for "non-blocking mode", then it is not just the read you have to wait for.  You are also waiting for the actual output initiated by the `write()` to complete.  If the `write()` is followed immediately`with `read()`, then there's no benefit to using "non-blocking mode".  If there's some computations or other I/O that can be performed in between, then non-blocking makes sense.  Otherwise let the `write()` block your program the exact amount of time it needs to complete instead of guessing at a delay time.